# R summary command doesn't show details of character variable

Tags: r

in R when I use summary(data.frame) command the results don't show the details of character variables.
for example summary(b) don't show how many male or female are there?
[example of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dmd6J.png) problem?

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: `table(<my variable name>)`.  Next time, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help you construct a *minimal reproducible example*.

Comment: This is the default behaviour of `summary` for vectors of type `character`. It makes no sense to determine `min`, `max` or similar quantities for characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you used a dummy for gender

```
gender_counts <- table(your_data$gender)
```

Then you can use `print()`

```
print(gender_counts)
```

Comment: Or, as I mentioned in my comment, simply `table(your_data$gender)`...

Answer (score 1):

To get top counts from `summary()`, you could first convert those character columns to factors:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
mpg_small <- ggplot2::mpg[,1:3]
glimpse(mpg_small)
#> Rows: 234
#> Columns: 3
#> $ manufacturer <chr> "audi", "audi", "audi", "audi", "audi", "audi", "audi", "…
#> $ model        <chr> "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4", "a4 quattro", "…
#> $ displ        <dbl> 1.8, 1.8, 2.0, 2.0, 2.8, 2.8, 3.1, 1.8, 1.8, 2.0, 2.0, 2.…

# character summary:
summary(mpg_small)
#>  manufacturer          model               displ      
#>  Length:234         Length:234         Min.   :1.600  
#>  Class :character   Class :character   1st Qu.:2.400  
#>  Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Median :3.300  
#>                                        Mean   :3.472  
#>                                        3rd Qu.:4.600  
#>                                        Max.   :7.000

mpg_fact <- mutate(mpg_small, across(1:2, as.factor))
glimpse(mpg_fact)
#> Rows: 234
#> Columns: 3
#> $ manufacturer <fct> audi, audi, audi, audi, audi, audi, audi, audi, audi, aud…
#> $ model        <fct> a4, a4, a4, a4, a4, a4, a4, a4 quattro, a4 quattro, a4 qu…
#> $ displ        <dbl> 1.8, 1.8, 2.0, 2.0, 2.8, 2.8, 3.1, 1.8, 1.8, 2.0, 2.0, 2.…

# factor summary:
summary(mpg_fact)
#>      manufacturer                 model         displ      
#>  dodge     :37    caravan 2wd        : 11   Min.   :1.600  
#>  toyota    :34    ram 1500 pickup 4wd: 10   1st Qu.:2.400  
#>  volkswagen:27    civic              :  9   Median :3.300  
#>  ford      :25    dakota pickup 4wd  :  9   Mean   :3.472  
#>  chevrolet :19    jetta              :  9   3rd Qu.:4.600  
#>  audi      :18    mustang            :  9   Max.   :7.000  
#>  (Other)   :74    (Other)            :177
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>